# Flask and D3.js error - Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, python, flask, d3.js

I'm having trouble sending back to my JavaScript file which utilizes a d3.json promise to query the Flask route like so:

```
ds.json("/").then(function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

My app.py is set up like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import pymongo
app = Flask(__name__)

# Use flask_pymongo to set up mongo connection
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/housing_db"
mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    data = mongo.db.price_index.find()
    return render_template("index.html", data = data)
```

And my index.html has the following script tags:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/test.js') }}"></script>
```

My question is, when I start the Flask application and check the console, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
Promise.then (async)
```

The folder structure is correct and follows the Flask required structure:

```
|-->flask_app.py
    |-->static
        |-->css
            |-->bootstrap.min.css
            |-->styles.css
        |-->js
            |-->jquery-3.1.1.min.js
            |-->bootstrap.min.js
            |-->script.js
    |-->templates
        |-->index.html
```

So I'm unsure why D3 is unable to get the data as expected. Has anyone run into this issue while using Flask? Most of the questions around here tend to be React.js based.

Comment: This exception is thrown when response is not json. "Unexpected token <" I guess, the response is html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a html template

`return render_template("index.html", data = data)`

But you are trying to load json...hence `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Because starting with `<` isn't valid json.

If you want json then you need to return valid json not html.

Presumably just...

`return JSON.stringify(data)`